Optimize program, where RAW stall occurs between div.d and sub.d (MIPS64)
My task it to find ways to optimize this program in MIPS64. Main problem is RAW stall between div.d and sub.d . Simply putting NOPs doesn't seem like a good solution. Also what I need is to not change the result of program
.text
div.d f7,f9,f10
mul.d f2,f4,f3
sub.d f7,f7,f4
ld r1,78(r0)
add.d f4,f5,f6
halt

I tried putting NOPs, tried putting sub.d at the end, but it didn't affected much.

You can swap the sub.d and the ld since that does not depend on any previous instruction.

div.d is unavoidably slow.  Your tiny program is too small to hide most of that latency even if the div.d is first and the sub.d is last.  (if you can change add.d to write a different register to avoid the WAR hazard.)  NOPs are useless, they just make the CPU waste time same as if it stalled on its own, but they waste space in the instruction cache.

I can add more lines of instructions or expand my program, but task is too not change result. For example, I cannot swap div.d and sub.d just to benefit from no RAW stall, because it will change the result of program

My task is "The task is to investigate the possibility of optimizing the program code
above and present a solution that will guarantee the correct order of execution
of the program instructions."
